# Convert Common Log Format (NCSA) to timestamp in bash/shell?

Tags: bash, shell, logging

Is there a simple way to convert Common Log Format (NCSA) to timestamp ?

I found only [C++ decision](http://www.thejach.com/view/2012/07/apaches_common_log_format_datetime_converted_to_unix_timestamp_with_c) and some perl decisions. And wonder why i can't use standart unix function like date.

```
> date +"%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S" -d "17/Oct/2013:16:52:28" +"%s"


"17/Oct/2013:16:52:28" -> 1382014348
```

For example:
Date in iso8601 to timestamp

```
 > date -d "2013-10-17T18:07:39+04:00" +"%S"
 1382018859
```

Comment: This use of `date` is not "standard unix" -- the `-d` option is, I think, a GNU extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this ( if you surely want to use `date`) ,

```
date -d "$(sed -e 's#/#-#g; s#:# #' <<< '17/Oct/2013:16:52:28')" '+%s'
```

Comment: Thank you, Sat. I knew that's must be easy.